# Angular 2 RxJs Promise not working for http.get call to C# Controller whereas Angular 2 In Memory Web API does work

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using ASP.NET Core and Angular 2 (version ~2.2.0) and Rxjs (version ^5.0.0-rc.5). The code sample in the angular.io docs works with the In Memory Web API for Angular 2 however when I make an http.get call to the C# Controller it fails. The data is being returned. The following lines of code don't work:

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

I've changed the code and these following lines of code do work:

```
getHeroes(): Hero[] {
    this.http.get(this.heroesUrl).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(heroes => {
        this.heroes = heroes;
    })
    return this.heroes;
}
```

Can anyone help? I really need to get the first lines of code to work because the second lines of code don't work as planned, they simply demonstrate that the data is being returned and being displayed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Why do you use `response.json().data` in one place and only `response.json()` in the other? Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: It's clear from the second example of code that the data is being returned from the C# Controller and is displayed by Angular 2. The first code example is from the angular.io docs and the Promise isn't working. I may change the Promise to an Observable to get it to work. It's not clear to me why the Promise isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use promise like this

```
return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
.map(response => response.json() as Ge)
       .toPromise()
       .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
       .catch(this.handleError);
```

}